# How to bind hierarchical json data using JQuery easyui combotree

Tags: jquery, json, combobox, jquery-easyui

I try to create combobox to show my data structure hierarchically, using easyui combotree JQuery plugin.

Simply I have the following JSON data structure:

jsonData:

```
[{
    "SubCategories": [{
        "SubCategories": [{
            "SubCategories": [],
            "id": 9,
            "name": "a11",
            "ParentId": 9
        }, {
            "SubCategories": [],
            "id": 10,
            "name": "a12",
            "ParentId": 10
        }],
        "id": 5,
        "name": "a1",
        "ParentId": 5
    }],
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A",
    "ParentId": 1
}, {
    "SubCategories": [{
        "SubCategories": [{
            "SubCategories": [],
            "id": 11,
            "name": "b11",
            "ParentId": 11
        }],
        "id": 6,
        "name": "b1",
        "ParentId": 6
    }],
    "id": 2,
    "name": "B",
    "ParentId": 2
}]
```

Html:

```
    <input class="jebs" name="xx" id="well"
       data-options="
        valueField:'id',
        textField:'text',
        panelHeight:'auto'
       ">
```

I try to bind json data in Ajax success like this:

```
 $('#well').combotree('loadData', $.parseJSON(jsonData));
```

I get this error:

> jquery.easyui.min.js:15623 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'options' of undefined

How can bind hierarchical json data structure using easyui combotree plugin ?

Comment: Also note that [only a single level of nesting is allowed per the HTML specification](https://select2.org/options#hierarchical-options).

Comment: @Kaddath you are right, I updated my question

Comment: @jom So It cannot be done.. I also tryed easyui combotree but didn't work neither..